# photo ranking tool

Tags: windows, linux, rating, lamp

I took a bunch of photos from a photo shoot, and I am trying to figure out my top five.

I got rid of all the bad ones, but that still leaves me with about ~40 or so that are decent to great. I want to post my top five to the group who was involved, but I'm having trouble organizing this on my Windows computer.

The Windows folder 'extra large icon' preview isn't sufficient, because they still aren't large enough to see fine detail in the photo, such as focus.

What I'm looking for is a head-to-head ranking workflow. It shows me two pictures, and I pick which one is better. The software works through all the images until they are all ranked, and I can then grab the top five.

I'm on Windows 10 and I have access to a Linux machine and a LAMP web server, so any Windows, Linux, or LAMP solution would suffice.